# Django Datetime Field to date

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to convert a datetime field to just date so I can agregate data by date.

```
list_transaction_line_agg = Transaction.objects.values(Date('trans_date'))
                                               .annotate(data_sum=Sum('amount'))
                                               .order_by()
```

However I can't seem to get it to work. The field `trans_date` is a `datetime` field and I just need to convert it to a `date`.

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    trans_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    trans_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.trans_type)
```

html

```
<h2>Agg</h2>
{% for Transaction in list_transaction_line_agg %}
( {{ Transaction.data_sum}}, {{ Transaction.trans_date }} )
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Was how I got it to work

```
list_transaction_line_agg = Transaction.objects.extra({'published':"date(trans_date)"}).values('published').annotate(data_sum=Sum('amount'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html, just do the following:

```
<h2>Agg</h2>
{% for Transaction in list_transaction_line_agg %}

( {{ Transaction.data_sum}}, {{ Transaction.trans_date|date:'d-M-Y' }} )

 {% endfor %}
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: it gave me this output  ( 500, 30-Aug-2015 ) ( 600, 30-Aug-2015 ), i think it needs to be handled in the view. because i want an aggregation by day ie. ( 1000, 30-Aug-2015)